# Enable SSL using certbot and nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, strapi, certbot

I am strying to set httpS on my Strapi production but it is very difficult. I followed the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@derrickmehaffy/using-strapi-in-production-with-https-717af82d1445) written by derrickmehaffy, but it does not work for me. :'(

My pm2 service:
[pm2 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUoT.png)

My /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf file :

```
# Strapi upstream server
upstream strapi-gatsby {
    server localhost:1337;
}
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/strapi.live-for-good.org.conf file :

```
server {
# Listen HTTP
    listen 80;
    server_name strapi.live-for-good.org;
# Define LE Location
    location ~ ^/.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      default_type "text/plain";
      root         /var/www/html;
    }
# Else Redirect to HTTPS // API
#    location / {
#      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    }
}
```

I cleared the default package in **sites-available** and **sites-enabled**, made the link, and when I wanted to check it with **service nginx configtest**, it fails

But, when I launch **sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload**, I got this :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

## System

```
Node.js version: 12.16.1
NPM version: 6.13.4
Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.19.3
Database: mongoDB on MLab
Operating system: ubuntu 18.04
```

Comment: please provide error code when you access to the website ?

Comment: does any have SSL configuration file for `strapi.live-for-good.org` domain ?

Comment: I tried to install certbot using the cerbot tutorial before, so there is a configuration, but not working